# Redux Saga global loading state

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is is possible in Redux Saga handle a global loading state? Inside my web application i need to call different microservices, and i don't want insert for each reducer a loading state like:

```
case Types.GET_BOOKS_SUCCESS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            data: action.payload.items,
            loader: false,
        };
}
```

I'm wondering if is possible to manage the loading state between actions, in order to understand if there are some pending sagas etc...

Comment: you could do it by creating a case to set the loader true, and another case to set it false. at the end loader is belong to the global state

Comment: global loading state should generally be avoided as it leads to worse UX

Answer (score -1):

You could represent loading state as a number. When you initiate a request, you increment the value. When you handle the response, you decrement the value. If the value is greater than 0, then at least one request is in flight.